# Java client can't connect to Redis Sentinel which is running on localhost

Tags: java, redis, jedis, redis-sentinel, redis-server

I have setup 3 Redis Server and 3 Redis Sentinel instances in my localhost. The servers are running at:

```
127.0.0.1:6379 // Master
127.0.0.1:6380 // Slave
127.0.0.1:6381 // Slave
```

and the sentinels are running at:

```
127.0.0.1:5000
127.0.0.1:5001
127.0.0.1:5002
```

I have a (Java) client that tries to connect to one of the sentinels and set the keys in redis server:

```
// import statements

public class RedisPush {

    private static final String MASTER_NAME = "mymaster";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "foobared";
    private static final Set sentinels;
    static {
        sentinels = new HashSet();
        sentinels.add("127.0.0.1:5000");
        sentinels.add("127.0.0.1:5001");
        sentinels.add("127.0.0.1:5002");
    }

    public static void pushToRedis() {

        Jedis jedis = null;

        try {
            JedisSentinelPool pool = new JedisSentinelPool(MASTER_NAME, sentinels);
            System.out.println("Fetching connection from pool.");
            jedis = pool.getResource();
            jedis.auth(PASSWORD);
            Socket socket = jedis.getClient().getSocket();

            System.out.println("Connected to " + socket.getRemoteSocketAddress());
            int i = 0;
            while (true) {
                jedis.set("sentinel_key" + i, "value" + i);
                System.out.println(i);
                i++;
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            if(jedis != null)
                jedis.close();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        while(true) {

            pushToRedis();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Initially, my sentinel configuration is as follows (for example, the first sentinel running on port `5000`):

```
bind 127.0.0.1
port 5000
sentinel monitor mymaster 127.0.0.1 6379 2
sentinel down-after-milliseconds mymaster 5000
sentinel failover-timeout mymaster 60000
sentinel auth-pass mymaster foobared
```

If I try to run my (Java) client, I get the following error:

```
Nov 23, 2018 1:52:57 AM redis.clients.jedis.JedisSentinelPool initSentinels
INFO: Trying to find master from available Sentinels...
Nov 23, 2018 1:52:57 AM redis.clients.jedis.JedisSentinelPool initSentinels
WARNING: Cannot get master address from sentinel running @ 192.168.0.102:5001. Reason: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused). Trying next one.
Nov 23, 2018 1:52:57 AM redis.clients.jedis.JedisSentinelPool initSentinels
WARNING: Cannot get master address from sentinel running @ 192.168.0.102:5000. Reason: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused). Trying next one.
Nov 23, 2018 1:52:57 AM redis.clients.jedis.JedisSentinelPool initSentinels
WARNING: Cannot get master address from sentinel running @ 192.168.0.102:5002. Reason: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused). Trying next one.
redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: All sentinels down, cannot determine where is mymaster master is running...
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisSentinelPool.initSentinels(JedisSentinelPool.java:180)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisSentinelPool.<init>(JedisSentinelPool.java:95)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisSentinelPool.<init>(JedisSentinelPool.java:82)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisSentinelPool.<init>(JedisSentinelPool.java:70)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisSentinelPool.<init>(JedisSentinelPool.java:44)
    at RedisPush.pushToRedis(RedisPush.java:29)
    at RedisPush.main(RedisPush.java:61)
```

However, if I change my sentinel configuration script to the one below:

```
# bind 127.0.0.1
port 5000
protected-mode no
sentinel monitor mymaster 127.0.0.1 6379 2
sentinel down-after-milliseconds mymaster 5000
sentinel failover-timeout mymaster 60000
sentinel auth-pass mymaster foobared
```

the client works perfectly. I don't understand why.

AFAIK, if `requirepass` is not set in `sentinel.conf` file AND `bind` is commented in `sentinel.conf` file, ONLY then `protected-mode` will be `yes` to avoid any client connecting to the sentinel apart from `localhost`. In my first sentinel configuration, I had the `bind` command but still it didn't work.

Why does commenting out `bind` and explicitly setting `protected-mode` to `no` works?

P.S. I also tried having both `bind 127.0.0.1` and `protected-mode no` but even that didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue where Jedis was throwing the same error, it was related to https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/issues/1367

To get around this on my mac I did `sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 127.0.1.1`
Then changed my sentinel.conf to `bind 127.0.1.1`
and then updated my yaml for spring data to connect to that ip

```
sentinel.nodes: 127.0.1.1:5000, 127.0.1.1:5002, 127.0.1.1:5003
```

Comment: sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 127.0.1.1 - solved my problem

Comment: HostAndPort.setLocalhost("127.0.0.1"); After addin this line its working fine for me.

Answer (score -1):

Jedis doesn't support well Redis Sentinel. Use Lettuce instead which has a better pool management.
And well supported on springboot too.

Comment: upvoted you because its true. Lettuce is better than Redis/Sentinel.